# hibernate: association with unmapped entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, associations, ternary

```
     table : map__company__branches (company_id int, branch_id int, is_primary_branch tinyint(1))

    public class company
    {
     @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinTable(name = "map__company__branches", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "company_id") })
     @MapKeyManyToMany(joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "branch_id") })
         @column(name="is_primary_branch")
         Map<Branch, Boolean> branchMap;
    }
```

Since Boolean type is not mapped entity so its giving error "targeting an unmapped class".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case you need collection mapping (`@ElementCollection` in JPA 2.0 annotations or `@CollectionOfElements` in Hibernate annotations) rather than relationship mapping (`@...To...`).

For example, with JPA 2.0 annotations:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "map__company__branches",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "branch_id")
@Column(name = "is_primary_branch")
Map<Branch, Boolean> branchMap;
```

Comment: @CollectionOfElements(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinTable(name = "map__company__branches", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "company_id") })
     @MapKey(columns = { @Column(name = "branch_id") })
         @column(name="is_primary_branch")
I have used this annoation. couldn't find @CollectionTable annotation. But error is still there

Comment: @Maddy: Which version of Hibernate do you use?

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.0.ga</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: 3.4.0.GA for hibernate annotation and 3.2.0 for hibernate. POM entries are in comment above.